# How to access constructor parameter to use as default parameter of another method in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self , name, gender, address):
        self.name = name 
        self.gender = gender 
        self.address = address 
    
    def edit_profile(self, new_city, new_gender, new_address, new_name = self.name):
        self.name = new_name
```

I am trying to set self.name from the constructor as default parameter for my method but
getting error "self" is not defined. Why is it showing the error why can't I access self.name in defult parameter but I can access it inside the method with self.name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a sentinel value like `None`, then check inside the body. `self` is not a keyword; it's just a parameter name that references an argument passed to the method. There is no instance available to get a name from when you *define* `edit_profile`.

```
def edit_profile(self, new_city, new_gender, new_address, new_name=None):
    if new_name is None:
        new_name = self.name
    ...
```

Comment: Very important thing to note is that default arguments are defined **at the moment of method definition**. No instance of `self` exists at this point

Comment: isn't  op want to reset/update `self.name` to `new_name`

Comment: Yes, and they can do that after the `if` statement; I just put `...` in to represent the rest of the body. (There's clearly more than *just* `self.name = new_name`, or the method wouldn't take so many arguments unrelated to the name.)

Comment: @sahasrara62 question is about default value of `new_name`, which OP wants to be `new_name = self.name`

Comment: @matszwecja he want that in the funciton parameters but  in code he use/assign the `self.name` to `new_name` which is is basically if new name is given as parameter  then update `self.name` to it else keep default to `self.name`

Comment: @sahasrara62 I'm perfectly aware of that, which is what code in the question achieves.

Comment: @sahasrara62 Yes, and one possibility is to only assign to `self.name` if `new_name` is not `None`.  The cost of a single assignment is negligible, though, and it simplifies the code to ensure that `new_name` is something you can assign to `self.name`, even if the resulting assignment is a no-op.

Comment: In short, it avoids making the assignment to `self.name` a special case compared to the other attributes.